# Play audio and video at the same time in Android

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play two different files at the same time.

I have tried to find players and tried to extend the default player achieving the same but couldn't get success in that. so please help me with it, by letting me know what's the best way to play audio file and video at the same time?

The reason I'm taking separate files is to save space, because the app will be localized, having multiple audio files for each language instead of having multiple videos saves space. That's important because android doesn't allow the download of app size above `50MB`.

Any help in this would be extremely helpful. And providing me code for this would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll never be able to synchronize things accurately this way, and large videos should probably be streamed anyway. Is there a reason you need to include the video in the app?

Comment: yes there is a new reason for that I am making an app which will be having video files but the audio would be according to the user's locale that's why I need to synchronize these files on run time. And the video is required for user's to understand the thing we are delivering to them.

Comment: Several audio streams can be encoded into the same media stream and the correct one can be selected during playback. Android's MediaPlayer has limited support for this functionality via the selectTrack method (you can only call it for audio in the prepared state). Encoding the video properly is your best bet.

Comment: If this is possible then can you suggest me the software or way encode video and play it with selected audio. Code example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend familiarizing yourself with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). There's a ton of documentation on their site. Or if you just really don't like command line tools, you may need to fork over some cash for a tool along the lines of Adobe Premiere (I'm sure there's cheaper options). Either way, your goal is to encode a file with one video stream and several audio streams. At that point, you should be able to use `getTrackInfo` and `selectTrack` in the `MediaPlayer` to pick the right audio stream at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with Audio Focus. Two or more Android apps can play audio to the same output stream simultaneously. The system mixes everything together. While this is technically impressive, it can be very aggravating to a user. To avoid every music app playing at the same time, Android introduces the idea of audio focus. Only one app can hold audio focus at a time.

When your app needs to output audio, it should request audio focus. When it has focus, it can play sound. However, after you acquire audio focus you may not be able to keep it until you’re done playing. Another app can request focus, which preempts your hold on audio focus. If that happens your app should pause playing or lower its volume to let users hear the new audio source more easily.

Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), when you call `requestAudioFocus()` you must supply an `AudioFocusRequest` parameter. To release audio focus, call the method `abandonAudioFocusRequest()` which also takes an `AudioFocusRequest` as its argument. The same `AudioFocusRequest` instance should be used when requesting and abandoning focus.

To create an `AudioFocusRequest`, use an `AudioFocusRequest.Builder`. Since a focus request must always specify the type of the request, the type is included in the constructor for the builder. Use the builder's methods to set the other fields of the request.

The following example shows how to use an `AudioFocusRequest.Builder` to build an `AudioFocusRequest` and request and abandon audio focus:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build();
focusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes)
        .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(afChangeListener, handler)
        .build();
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
final Object focusLock = new Object();

boolean playbackDelayed = false;
boolean playbackNowAuthorized = false;

// ...
int res = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest);
synchronized(focusLock) {
    if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) {
        playbackNowAuthorized = false;
    } else if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        playbackNowAuthorized = true;
        playbackNow();
    } else if (res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_DELAYED) {
       playbackDelayed = true;
       playbackNowAuthorized = false;
    }
}

// ...
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            if (playbackDelayed || resumeOnFocusGain) {
                synchronized(focusLock) {
                    playbackDelayed = false;
                    resumeOnFocusGain = false;
                }
                playbackNow();
            }
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            synchronized(focusLock) {
                resumeOnFocusGain = false;
                playbackDelayed = false;
            }
            pausePlayback();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            synchronized(focusLock) {
                resumeOnFocusGain = true;
                playbackDelayed = false;
            }
            pausePlayback();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // ... pausing or ducking depends on your app
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Also you can check Android's official documentation. If this doesn't help, you can [check](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-multiple-sound-sources-in-android-with-audio-focus/) this site and this [site](https://markojerkic.com/handling-audio-focus-in-android/) for more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To play audio: [Audio Track reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)
To play video: [Media Player reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

And now you could start on the main thread by showing in a [Video View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) the video you want, and when is the time to play the sound you start playing the Audio Track. The tricky part will be to syncronize the audio with the video

Comment: Yes playing two different thing can be done, but then synchronize would be a pain, which will degrade the quality of the application as well.

Comment: This was the way I chose to create a similar application. I didn't found any other solution.

Comment: Can you provide me some of your code to achieve this task? may be it can help through this.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't do that. But the idea is simple. Play the video as the link to Video view and Media  Player shows you and while the video is playing you have a while(isPlaying) loop. In this loop you take the System.currentTimeMillis() and check the difference between the start of the video and the current time. if the difference is equals with the offset you want you start playing the audio. ( assuming that you know the time when you want to play the sound file ).